# Isekai cultivation manhua with multiple reincarnations

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics, cultivation

I'm looking for a manhua where the MC is a girl who was isekai’d/transmigrated into a cultivation world. In her first life she joins a sect and gets a master then she dies and is a reincarnated a few years later with all her memories intact. Her master is able to find her and takes her as his disciple again. She dies and reincarnates a few times and her master always finds her. I think she had a System too. There was a time when she reincarnates into a little dragon. Her master ends up ascending.

I stopped at that point in the story. The story isn’t complete yet but I really like it and I kept it on the shelf for a bit so the chapters could pile up but now I can’t remember the name and I can’t find where I wrote it down. It was an intense cliffhanger for me cause I was looking forward to their romance.

Comment: When you return, you can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is a little old but I know the answer, the story you're looking for is [My disciple died yet again](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/my-disciple-died-yet-again/).

Just as an FYI, she didn't have a system rather she spoke to a character via a system like interface between incarnations.

She gets recruited by said character to solve "bugs"; that is things that cause catastrophic levels of damage to the world that come into existence due to the solution. During which she dies and get's reincarnated multiple times whilst keeping her memories to try and fix the bug or find an alternate solution (it makes sense once you read it, promise!).

The first time she dies she comes back as a baby and her master practically kidnaps her. She then comes back as a dude (she does not have a good ending this time), then as a dragon (stars small but very quickly grows to be as big as a mountain) and then a few times in the immortal/spirit/god/divine realm (where her master accends to) and so on and so fourth.

It's a relatively short Xianxia story of around 370 chapters, it's written mostly as a comedy poking fun at xianxia cliches and tropes

If you ever want to get into Xianxia (or just want an interesting story) it's a very good read, highly recommend it.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with answering old, unresolved story identification questions!  And there are some unsolved that are much older than 1/1/2021.